# How to Unit Test namespaced models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, namespaces, shoulda

In my Rails app, I make heavy use of subdirectories of the model directory and hence of namespaced models - that is, I have the following directory heirarchy:

```
models
|
+- base_game
|  |
|  +- foo.rb (defines class BaseGame::Foo)
|
+- expansion
   |
   +- bar.rb (defines class Expansion::Bar)
```

This is enforced by Rails - that is, it Just Doesn't Work to call the classes "just" `Foo` and `Bar`.

I want to unit test these classes (using Shoulda on top of ActiveSupport::TestCase). I know that the name of the class-under-test will be derived from the name of the test case class.

How do I write unit tests that will test these classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it is straight-forward, even under normal `ActiveSupport` / `Test::Unit`. Simply duplicate the model directory structure under `/test`:

```
test
|
+- base_game
|  |
|  +- foo_test.rb (defines class BaseGame::FooTest)
|
+- expansion
   |
   +- bar_test.rb (defines class Expansion::BarTest)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work directly, I use Rspec and it's straight:

```
describe User::Profile do

  it "should exist" do
    User::Profile.class.should be_a Class
  end

  it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that worked for me with both `ruby -I` and `zeus`:

```
require "test_helper"

class BaseGame::Foo < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include BaseGame

  should "let #baz do something" do
    assert Foo.new.baz
  end

end
```

You can also do

```
require "test_helper"

class BaseGame::Foo < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  should "let #baz do something" do
    assert BaseGame::Foo.new.baz
  end

end
```